# Radiobuttonlist? When I select a radiobutton I want to unselect by clicking again the selected radio button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I use `asp:radiobuttonlist` and have 2 radio's, e.g. YES / NO.

I want to able to give the user the ability to undo a selection after they clicked YES or NO, by clicking YES or NO again.

For example, a user clicks on YES but he thinks "no, I will answer this later". They can't undo the selection... They must choose YES or NO.

Is there a way to make it so that when the user clicks on YES, yes is selected and when they click YES again, it should be unselected... The outcome should be that yes and no are not filled/clicked/selected?

I don't want to add a 3rd radio button as an option. just want to able to give the user functionality so that when he clicks again on a selected item, it should be unselected... Desired result: Both are unselected.

I need to think in the direction of jQuery, right?

Comment: If it's just a yes / no selection, instead of having two radio buttons, it might be better in terms of User Experience to have a single check-box? It won't allow for a "neither" option though, so wont solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't the expected behaviour of a radiobutton - you don't click it again to negate it. If you want that you should look at checkbox/checkboxlist.

Comment: I want this behaviour: If they choose, they can only choose one, but they should be able to unclick that. With checkboxlist they can choose multiple right?

Comment: but I don't want multiple selection.

Comment: You could either force single selection of some checkboxes or add un-check functionality to radio buttons. Either of these options are rather terrible in terms of User Experience design though... So terrible that I, for one, am not going to elaborate on how it could be done.

Comment: sorry.. but for me this is a reasonable question from a user. If the user wants undo (not required field) he should be able to do that. Nothing miss with this question. The same for textbox.. he types a text, but then he changes thoughts, and makes the field blank. The same here field ) not required radiobutton list, should be unclickable... just my design thoughts... but thanks for your idea.

Comment: I agree that it's a valid thing for a user to want to do, but I think that the mechanism for doing it should not be to force radio buttons to behave unlike every other radio button on the web. My solution and Michael Durrant's solution both achieve your goal without altering behaviour of common GUI elements.

Comment: @mesut - take a look at the guidelines from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511488.aspx - what you're trying to do will confuse most users who have experience of web pages.

Comment: I think you're right guys... Also looking at msdn guidelines. You convinced me.

Answer (score 2):

You could give them a third "undecided" radio button? As shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/9Hucx/).

Comment: this is the option that I don't want. I don't want a 3rd option.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll leave the solution here as a potential solution to the general problem.

Answer (score 1):

think outside the box.
Use a label like 'Include this?'
with a checkbox that we they can check and uncheck to their hearts desire
Mostly gui questions like this are about the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use a checkboxgroup and bind click handler to deselect the others of that group:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").bind('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    $("input[type='checkbox'][name='" + name + "'][id!='" + $(this).attr('id') + "']").map(function() {
        $(this).prop('checked', false); return this;
    }).checkboxradio('refresh');
});
```